# Send float value using handler

Tags: android, android-service, arrays, android-handler

I want to send float values from a service to my UI (with small precision - two digits only like 1204,74). For now I want this float as string because I want only display it but later I will use this float as a number.

Service

```
...
int A = Integer.parseInt(listBytesAnsw.get(2), 16);
int B = Integer.parseInt(listBytesAnsw.get(3), 16);
float rpm = (A*255+B)/4;
msgBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putFloat(rpm).array();
mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.RPM, msgBuffer.length,-1, msgBuffer).sendToTarget();
addToQueue("01 0C");
...
```

UI

```
switch (msg.what) {
...
case Constants.RPM:
byte[] readRpmBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
String rpm = new String (readRpmBuf,0,msg.arg1);
mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName + ": " + rpm);
break;
...
```

I don't get float from service but only random signs. Something is wrong but I don't know what. I rarely used byte arrays so I don't get it to much.

Comment: ByteBuffer != String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Service:

```
var DataToSend = Convert.ToString(rpm);
```

Send the data in the service as a string and then convert it back to a float in the UI.

You can then use `str.ToCharArray()`

This is a good practice for a lot of services that need a low amount of data to be converted to and back from a string.

Comment: I do something like this `String sRpm = Float.toString(rpm);                            mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.RPM, sRpm).sendToTarget();` in Service and `String rpm = (String) msg.obj;` in UI. It works but I get rounded result.

Comment: AH. In the service times (*) your float by 100 (or however many points of precision you need) before making it a float.  Then in the UI, divide it by the same amount (100) after you have it converted back into a float.

Comment: Gary, please mark the answer if everything is working correctly, or reply back if you are still seeing unexpected behavior.

Comment: I debuged app and I saw that the `rpm` is rounded during calculating, not by handler. I added `(float)` casting but it still is rounded. I times it also but still it's rounded. I cant figure it out.

Comment: If it's rounding in your calculation then at least this answer works for your original question.  Mark it and then we can move on your next problem.

Comment: Post your calculation code in a new question, and then post the link to it here.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/34442364/rounded-result-even-casting-to-float